# C# Serial Port Reading returns random line breaks

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to read from my ELM327, did set it up.
As an example in teraterm, when I send Command `ATI` I received response

```
>ATI
ELM327 v1.3
```

I know carriage return should be `\r`, according to manual `0x0D` for outgoing and incoming.
Now in my code I use `ReadExisting()` and that gives me multiple empty lines,
sometimes it displays `ELM327 v1.3` but sometimes it  can be:

```
/>
ATI

ELM3
27 v1.3
```

I am having difficulties to make it nice and clear one line response.

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort(ComsList.GetItemText(ComsList.SelectedItem), bauds[2], Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPort.NewLine = "\r";
_serialPort.DataReceived  += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            lastMessage = indata;
            Debug.Print(indata);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried with something like PuTTY? Does it show the same thing?

Comment: yes, like I mentioned above, I used teraterm to compare responses. and it doesn't show the same. Always shows correct one liner

Comment: Well I think the problem is that you're just receiving the data in chunks and the newlines aren't actually part of the received data, but just part of the `Debug.Print()` call. The documentation says "Writes a message ***followed by a line terminator*** to the trace listeners in the Listeners collection". Instead of printing what you get every time the event is handled, you should be appending to a buffer until 0x0D is encountered and treat the entire buffer up to that point as a single message to print/evaluate.

Comment: Well yes, but I am not only printing it, if I use ReadLine but also Debug.Print didn't supposed to add new line termination, i do get same result which is multiple lines, but maybe that's just wrong interpretation of ReadExisting ?
Another thing I don't understand why I am getting Echo of command sent in the buffer. (I can turn it off later with command, but teraterm doesn't do it without turning it off? )

Comment: it seems to me that the `port_DataReceived` event is probably not the best approach for reading from your device. May be you should try a synchronous approach. Write => read in while loop. Could you post the entire message that you receive in teraterm ? containing all characters that the device is sending

Comment: Like I said, if the data you receive doesn't contain a 0x0D byte, the message from the device isn't complete. You shouldn't be doing anything with incomplete messages beyond buffering the data. Just store what you've received until you get the message terminator.

Comment: teraterm gives me `>ATI
ELM327 v1.4`
With line break after ATI and after next line five blank new line

So maybe ReadByte will be better approach then

Comment: It will work either way. You just need to handle "messages" instead of relying on the complete message being available when you go to read from the device.

Comment: You are right, I think it will be better to have a full control on what I am receiving. I will  use ReadByte Method

Answer (score 0):

The comments are wrong, using the `DataReceived` event is the proper way to go about this. The `Debug.Print(indata);` is adding a carriage return and line feed to your print out.  Try using `Console.Write(indata)` as it won't tack on anything extra.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.print?view=netcore-3.1

> Writes a formatted string followed by a line terminator to the trace
> listeners in the Listeners collection.